# How to re-position popup with Scrolling containers

Tags: javascript, html

Your reference element and popover could be located anywhere in the DOM. For example your reference element and popover element could be in different scrolling containers. Popover needs to handle any DOM context you throw at it.

Take the following HTML:

```
<div id="scroll">
  Lots of text here
  <button id="reference">My Button</button>
  Lots of text here
</div>

<div id="tooltip">My Centered Tooltip</div>
```

When the scrolling container is scrolled, the reference element will change its location on the screen. However your tooltip is not "aware" of this happening, and so it won't track the reference element as it's scrolling.